# How to change the color of first option in select using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a dropdown as

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cntry
 (SelectList(ViewBag.Country), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

Here my requirement is I want the first option  --Select-- to be displayed as red in any case i.e; if it is selected or not while the rest should be grey color.However I managed to do something like...

```
select:first-child {
    color:red;
}    
option:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

and now the code aboveworks fine and when I change the option from select to another that value is grey in color but if I click anywhere on the screen that value changes it color to red which is not my requirement. I want only the --Select-- to be red while the other being grey in color either selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery.

```
$("#Cntry > option").each(function(index) {
    //alert(this.index + ' ' + this.value);
    if(index == 0){
       $(this).attr('style','color:red');
    }
    else{
       $(this).attr('style','color:grey');
    }
});
```

**Example:**http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/1495/

Comment: @Jalmin Soni how can I show the first index as red in color. Thanks

Comment: I have update fiddle link please check it and let me know is it working or not .